# How to get decimals in an input number field to register in its value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have an input field within ReactJS:

```
<input
    type="number"
    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
    maxLength={3}
    min="0"
    max="999"
    step=".1"
    onPaste={handlePaste}
    pattern="[0-9]*"
/>
```

Here are the associated functions:

```
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length >= e.target.maxLength) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    const key = e.key;
    if (!allowChars(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function allowChars(charValue) {
    const acceptedKeys = '0123456789.';
    return acceptedKeys.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
}

function handlePaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

When I log `e.target.value`, and type `....` into the input field, the decimals do not register. Why is this? And how can I get them to register?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by _"the decimals do not register."_?

Comment: When I log `e.target.value`, and type decimals into the input field, the input's value logs blank.

Comment: do you mean this code? `console.log(e.target.value.length);` you are logging the `length`...

Comment: @Sagivb.g Edited my code, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pattern` attribute doesn't allow `.`. Change it to `pattern="[0-9.]*"`.

There's probably no need to use `pattern`, though. Since it's `type="number"`, it should only allow valid numbers, which makes the pattern redundant.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use the `onKeyPress` event, which will fire both for the key-down and key-up.
So when the key down is fired, your initial value is blank.

You can use the `onChange` event to trigger the handler only after the change accours:

```
onChange={handleKeyPress}
```

---

Running example:

```js
function handleKeyPress(e) {
  debugger
  console.log(e.target.value);
  if (e.target.value.length >= e.target.maxLength) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.maxLength);
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  const key = e.key;
  if (!allowChars(key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function allowChars(charValue) {
  const acceptedKeys = '0123456789.';
  return acceptedKeys.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
}

function handlePaste(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

const App = () => (
  <div >
    <input
      type="number"
      onChange={handleKeyPress}
      maxLength={3}
      min="0"
      max="999"
      step=".1"
      onPaste={handlePaste}
      pattern="[0-9]*"
    />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The decimal is not being logged.

Comment: you mean the `.` (dot) by itself without any numbers following?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean. if you run my code snippet what exactly isn't being logged? keep in mind that input of type number will [only return valid numbers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type%3Dnumber))

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your input tag with the step="any".